# Detecting child process creation in fork()

Tags: c++, unix, fork

The `fork()` system call makes two identical copies of the address space, one for parent, the other for the child.

When using fork with an if statement, how many times will the child process be created in the following code?

```
fork();
pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{
fork();
}
```

Comment: Five times. Do you need further explanation?

Comment: "makes two identical copies of the address space" - no, it doesn't. It makes one identical copy of an already existing address space. And on most modern implementations, it doesn't even do that - it just creates a new address space that references all the same pages as the original, but marks them for copy-on-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a little extra code to get something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0) printf("%d\n", pid);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0) printf("%d\n", pid);
    if(pid==0)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid != 0) printf("%d\n", pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile, execute, and check its output: **5 child process IDs**.